# Trying to create a confirmation for my code so that it will allow user to change answer

Tags: python, confirm

I wanted to add a confirmation for my code so that the user will be able to change their input. I haven't yet added the loop for the question but for some reason when I run this it fails to run def calc() and therefore the calculations I created cannot continue. Help!!

```
n=0
x=0
while True:
    numbers = input("Please enter a, b,c, or, d to select a equation")
    if numbers == "a":
        n =3
        x = 2
        break

    elif numbers =="b":
        n = 4
        x = 5
        break

    elif numbers == "c":
        n=5
        x=6
        break
    elif numbers == "d":
        n=6
        x=7
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a,b,c, or d")

w = float(input("Please enter weight"))
choice = input("Is this your answer?")
if choice == "yes":
    def calc():
        if n > w :
            weight = (x - w)
             weight2 = weight/n
            print(weight)
        elif w < x:
            weight = (w - x)
            weight2 = weight/n
            print(weight)
    calc()
elif choice =="no":
    print ("Lets change it")
else:
   print("Please respond with 'yes' or 'no'")
```

Comment: Don't define a function in a conditional part of the code. If you're using it in several places you need to be sure it exists. In any case, you seem to be using it only once here, so why define a function at all?